# Importing multiple categories with Magento

Tags: magento, csv, import

Been all day on this one : 
I have a bunch of categories in Magento and I'm importing a CSV of about 1000 products.  Each product is going into ~10 categories.
I've tried formatting the CSV the same way that the CSV that I once exported :

```
sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category, ....
"12345","","Default","simple","myFavoriteCategory", ....
,,,,"myFavoriteCategory/and a subcategory", ....
,,,,"myFavoriteCategory/badSubcategory", ....
```

I thought this was great but it's only putting the product into the first category (`myFavoriteCategory` in this case)

I also tried doing it all in one line by separating the categories by double delimeters within the quotes but with no success.
I'm using Magento ver. 1.6.2.0

Thanks

Comment: How are you importing? Using Magentos builtin import, or a 3rd party extension like Magmi, or your own module/code?

Comment: I am using Magento's built-in import.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a 1.6.2.0 version at hand, but in a 1.7.0.2 system the column `_category` is usually followed by `_root_category`. Is this also true for 1.6.2.0? If so, did you define `_root_category` values properly? Other than that: is this a multi website/store setup or just a single store?

Comment: thanks, I will try this and report back with results.

Comment: I tried adding the `_root_category` attribute with no luck.  I put the field in the initial product line as well as all of the subsequent lines.  No go.  I'm going to try Magmi now.

Comment: No luck at first pass with Magmi although I will keep trying.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Magmi plugin, which is fairly easy to install, I followed these instructions : 
http://blog.maximusbusiness.com/2012/11/import-categories-images-product-attributes/ 
and it worked.  I hope I can save someone in the future some serious head/wall contact.

Comment: You earned a point only for the sentence:
"I can save someone in the future some serious head/wall contact."